# How to bring back GUI in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gui

I was using Ubuntu quite well. Then I have mistakenly deleted all the lightdm folder file. Now my GUI is lost. Please help me to recover my GUI. Thank you.

For more information: Installing Lightdm again not working.

And these not working too:

```
sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You broke your package system. The system does not know what packages you removed. Therefore, reinstalling ubuntu-desktop does not work, as it has not been removed, and as it is not known to the system which dependent packages are missing.

You can however reinstall an Ubuntu system without losing current settings and data. Boot with the Ubuntu 18.04 installation CD or USB. Start the install procedure. Select "Something else" on the screen that offers you a few choices on how to proceed. This will bring you to a screen that allows you to control partitioning and mount points yourself. Here, indicate that your current system partition should be mounted to "/". The important point here is to make sure that **the format checkbox is unchecked**. This way, the partition will not be erased. All system files will be overwritten, but not your user data and configuration.

If you have a partition schema different from the default of Ubuntu 18.04 (only a root partition), then you will need to indicate mount points for other partitions (possibly a swap or a separate /home) as well.

Comment: Reinstalling the OS was probably not necessary. The OP knew what files they deleted and could simply [find what package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) (probably `lightdm`) provided them and *re*install that package. The OP reported that *installing* `lightdm` did not fix the problem, but *re*installing it by passing the `--reinstall` flag (as [N0rbert suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112647/how-to-bring-back-gui-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1112719#comment1837183_1112647) and [Abhishek mishra has since reiterated](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164686/22949)) will typically work.

Comment: FWIW I tried everything else and this finally did solve my problem. Sometimes you really do need to reinstall the OS. Be careful how you wield `apt purge`!

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

(As [N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) suggested [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112647/how-to-bring-back-gui-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1164686#comment1837183_1112647).)